# Pressflow + CDN, node access counter not updating

Tags: 6, caching, cdn

I am using Pressflow (Boost+Varnish) with "boost ajax stat block" enabled for stats, things were working ok and node counter was getting updated. Few days ago I started using full-site acceleration via CDN and the node access counter (page reads) is no longer updating ?

In theory boost ajax stat should work with caching, why is it not in this case ?

Website : http://www.megaleecher.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a working solution.

Module - http://drupal.org/project/jstats gets the job done, make sure to copy the **jstats.php** file into root.

Thanks